# Decomposition that does not preserve functional dependency

Tags: relational-database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

When can a BCNF decomposition not preserve functional dependency... I am trying to figure this out for say R=(V,W,X,Y,Z)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of a BCNF decomposition is to **eliminate** functional dependencies that are *not* of the form `key -> everything else`

So if a table has a FD, say A -> B, such that A is not a key, it means you're storing redundant data in your table.  As a result, you create a new table with columns A and B, with  A being the key, then you remove B from your original table.

As a result of this change you would no longer suffer from deletion anomalies, nor would you have to update multiple rows just to make a change to the A -> B relationship.

So for a trivial, naive example, let's say you have a employee table with columns:

```
 employeeId   name   jobTitle    salary
```

Assume that `jobTitle -> salary` that is, everyone with the same job title always makes the same salary.  Assume a jobTitle of "developer" equates to a salary of $90,000.  If you have 20 developers in your database, it would be silly to store the same redundant value of $90,000 for each row.  So, you drop the salary column from your employees table, and create a new salary table with:

```
 jobTitle_[key]   salary
```

Then, to get a salary on an employee, you look it up in the salary table.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense but is there a case where you have a BCNF that does not preserve dependencies?

Answer (score 12):

Taken from [Database Design and Relational Theory](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025276.do):

```
R = (S, J, T)

{S, J} -> {T}
{T} -> {J}
```

This is not in BCNF, since `T -> J` holds and `T` is not a key.

Decomposing it into `R1 = (T, J)` and `R2 = (T, S)` with `{T}` and `{T, S}` being keys resp. leads to BCNF.

However, the dependency `{S, J} -> {T}` is lost.

Comment: How does `S` be the key for `R2`? Isn't it `(T, S)` is a valid relation for BCNF only because there is no dependency between `T` and `S`?

Comment: @soobster he's not saying `S` is a key for `R2`, he's saying `{T, S}` as a whole is one

Answer (score 1):

R(a b c d e) with FDs { A->B,AC->D,BD->E}.
In this relation AC is a Candidate key and This relation is not in 2NF as non prime B is partial dependent on key(AC). 
To convert this relation into bcnf decompose into two relations : R1(a b )    {a->b}  key = a
R2(a c d e) {ac->de} key =a
Both R1 and R2 are in bcnf as every determinant is a key, but they are not dependency preserving as bd->e is lost.

Comment: Key should be equal to "ac" rather that just "a" for R2

Answer (score 0):

```
Schema R=(V,W,X,Y,Z)

Functional dependencies:

V,W -> X
Y,Z -> X
  W -> Y
```

Decompose to BCNF and you will see that all FD's can not be preserved in a single decomposition.

Comment: @stackuser When we say 'decomposition' here we mean *lossless* decomposition. Yours is not lossless. (What is the reasoning behind "since"?)